# Show that change of variable theorem holds for $\cup A_i$

Tags: integration, analysis

Problem assumes the following theorem

> $\mathtt{Theorem}$
>   Let A be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\phi:A \to \mathbb R^n$ a one-to-one continuously differentiable map whose Jacobian $J\phi$ is nowhere zero on A. Suppose that the function $f:\phi(A) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and is zero outside a compact subset of $\phi(A)$ and that $\int_{\phi(A)}f$ exists. Then $\int_{\phi(A)}f=\int_{A}(f\circ\phi)|J\phi|$.

Main problem is following.

> Suppose $A_i$, $i=1,2,3,...$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ such that the theorem is true for each $A_i$ and the restriction of $\phi$ to $A_i$. Let $A=\cup A_i$. Show that the theorem is true for $A$ and $\phi$.

I thought that I can show that it is true for $A_1\cup A_2$, then with monotone convergence theorem, I can show it. But I can't show even two union.

Furthermore it cannot be assumed that f is positive.

I can't understand why the theorem mention the compact subset of $\phi(A)$ and how to solve this problem.